# Crontab won't execute script

Tags: linux, bash, cron

Here's my cron:

**crontab -l**

```
30 2 * * * /usr/sbin/stime&
32 2 * * * /usr/sbin/rtc -s
30 2 2 * * /usr/sbin/rtc -c
00 5 * * * /path/to/script/backup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Here's my script:

**backup.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

rsync -e"ssh -i /path.to/id_rsa" -aP MyUsername@HostIP:/path/to/host/backup/ /path/to/local/backup --exclude '*.sql'
```

If I run **backup.sh** from command line it is executed. Cron won't run it.

I thought it may be a rghts issue so I modified command in crontab like this:

```
00 5 * * * su - root -c /path/to/script/backup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Still no execution from crontab. Time and date are correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't redirect the output, it might contain the reason. Use full path to rsync.

Comment: Recommendation: avoid usage of `~username/path/to/something` or `~/path/to/something` and use full paths.

Comment: I have changed every path to full path and it does not work. I get rid of redirection of output and this changes nothing. Nothing to show becouse script wasn't executed = no log of event that didn't happen.

Comment: Add output of `ls -ld /path/to/script/backup.sh`.

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          240 Mar  5 11:35 /path/to/script/backup.sh

Comment: If you think it is a rights issue, add the entry to root's crontab: 'sudo crontab -e'

Comment: What's the full path to rsync?

Comment: It's /bin/rsync and I already put full path in the script.

Comment: Change `>/dev/null 2>&1` to `>/tmp/backup.out 2>&1` then look at that file  after the next scheduled run.

Comment: I'm surprised and confused becouse when I changed output from null to file, like @RedGrittyBrick suggested, cron finally executed the script. File contains typical progress of rsync command (bytes, percent, speed and time info). But it done the job like it supposed to. I can't explain why it worked but it did, and this is the only change I maked from previous try. Can it be the -P parameter in the script caused all this problem for cron to run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Don't discard potentially useful messages

Whenever a cron job fails mysteriously, my first action is usually to redirect STDOUT and STDERR into files in /tmp so I can see any error messages and other potentially helpful output.

So the cron entry would be

```
00 5 * * * /path/to/script/backup.sh >/tmp/backup.out 2>&1
```

### Make scripts self documenting

I also usually ensure something useful is written there by adding
diagnostic output to the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Backup starting..."
date
rsync -e"ssh -i /path.to/id_rsa" \
      -aP MyUsername@HostIP:/path/to/host/backup/ \ 
      /path/to/local/backup \
      --exclude '*.sql'    
echo "Backup ended"
```

### Check the man pages

The man page for rsync says

```
-q, --quiet
This option decreases the amount of information you are given during the 
transfer, notably suppressing information messages from the remote server. 
This option is useful when invoking rsync from cron.
```

So it is likely that when rsync output is directed to /dev/null, rsync notices that STDOUT is not connected to a terminal or regular file and terminates with an error condition.

You could perhaps verify this by changing the cron command to

```
00 5 * * * /path/to/script/backup.sh >/dev/null 2>/tmp/backup.err
```

and then reviewing the contents of `/tmp/backup.err`

However adding the `-q` option would be an appropriate solution.

### A batch shell isnt like an interactive shell

Generally, when running from cron there are some major differences to 
running interactively

- You cant rely on environment variables being set (major gotcha)
- There isn't a TTY attached to the process (some programs depend on this)
- etc

So when things don't work as expected you should reconsider how all these might affect what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

One very tricky source of a cron program (Red Hat) not working is 
when you use:   crontab -e

to edit the cron file,

you must EXIT, not just save.

Thus :w   and then staying in the file will not instantiate the
changes. 
you must use :wq    ( VIM command )